# Can i encode or decode video in Android using OpenCORE or StageFright?

Tags: android, media, codec, stagefright, opencore

Does this Android Frameworks give capabilities for develop encoding and decoding functions for one Android app?

I know there is one high level API with 4.1 named MediaCodec which gives the capabilities for encoding and decoding video, but i dont know if it really uses one of that Media Frameworks as Stagefright for access to the codecs.

Which are the benefitis encoding or decoding using directly one of that frameworks than using the MediaCodec API?

Maybe i'm very confused but i have to make a project about encoding with Android video and i have to choose the better option for this, if anybody can help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MediaCodec api and not any lower level api. The MediaCodec api will then use the appropriate framework internally. This is because android vendors will integrate their own codecs and hardware / dsp accelerated codecs into the framework and set those as default for MediaCodec api. They will ensure their codecs work with MediaCodec api.  If you use MediaCodec api it will work on all devices irrespective of the framework being used below. That is what that api is for.

Unless you specifically want to do some testing with OpenCore/Stagefright don't go there.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

So if Android 4.1 is now using the StageFright framework, then, MediaCodec will use the codecs integrated in that framework, isn't it?

But my question is, before the MediaCodec API was released, how was the process for encoding one video in, for example, h.264 using the hardware of one device? Can you give me one example? 

Exists any benefit (like for example, in time) in doing the task using directly the frameworks?

Comment: @user1735358, there was always a high level java api available for encoding.  If I am right MediaCodec is actually a lower level access within the java framework. MediaPlayer / MediaRecorder was always available. MediaCodec has been added to provide lower level control. If you don't need lower level access you should use MediaPlayer / MediaRecorder

Comment: Wow, thanks again @av501, i though MediaPlayer and MediaRecorder were only for record video/audio and play it. 

Is it possible to record video from the cam device with that classes using HW encoding from MediaCodec?

The idea of my project is to record video in raw format and encoding it using the HW device. Do you think is it possible to connect with MediaRecorder or should i look for another classes? Thx!!

Comment: @javiaf, getting raw format is possible, but not effective it will not run more than 10 fps except on the highest end phones. I am not clear on what you need to achieve. If you want to capture from the camera you can capture raw video. If you want to encode using the best HW codec on the device, trust me the manufacturer would have already made it a default config of MediaRecorder, so you should simply use that. If you want to save YUV and give it out of the pone to encode somewhere else, then yes you can do that.

Comment: the idea is to capture the video from the camera and encode using HW for sending the video encoded using RTP. The idea is encoding faster than sw, but as i understand you, the MediaRecorder makes one SW encoding by its own, so it would be not useful to make one HW encoding, cause the video its encoded yet. 

So what i want to do is to record, encode by HW and later send it by network. 

"If you want to save YUV and give it out of the pone to encode somewhere else, then yes you can do that" -> Can you talk me more about it?

Comment: If you want to encode on the phone, I am still not clear on what HW you want to use? MediaRecorder will use on an actual device that has a HW encoder the hw encoder.  If you want to encode outside the phone, you need save yuv on sd card then pull it out and then encode.  I am guessing you simply want to use the fastest encoder available on the device, which any manufacturer would have already implemented on the device.

Comment: Ah!! So then MediaCodec is good for encode with HW from external video files, isnt it? I mean, if you have one file decoded in one format and u wanna encode it, then use MediaCodec, but if you wanna capture from Camera of the device, then MediaRecorder encode the stream of video using HW codecs, is it right?

Okay, you asked me which codecs i wanna use? There is a class MediaCodecInfo that says which HW codecs your device can use, so i would like to make one APP that in principle check which encoders can your device use and then, you can choose, encode it, and (not my work) send it by RTP.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html 

One example: How can i assure that if one Nexus 4 can encode in H.264 using lowlevel as MediaCodecInfo can check, when i write this: recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264); the codecs im using are HW codecs and not SW codecs? With that answer i think my problem is nearly solved.

Comment: You cannot guarantee anything. The manufacturer would have modified android to do that for him. So if he has not, it won't. But all decent phones will use the h/w encoder and not the s/w encoder for performance reasons. Else you will not get all the encoding specs they give out.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is done by vendor/integrators. The best solution would be (if you have access to customized source code of the platform -> if not, use any free board) to integrate your HW enc with libstagefright (as OMX component) in this way you will have encoding of YUV done along with encapsulation into any desired (from supported ones) format, then you can use some high level rtp api to encapsulate and manage streaming (just conclude from a uncle google answer about android and rtp).